# Find the Inverse Fourier Transform of $ \frac{6 \exp(4iw) \sin(2w)}{ 9 + w²} $

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I have been asked to calculate the inverse fourier transform of the equation

$$ \frac{6\exp(4iw)\sin(2w)}{(9 + w²)}$$

I have managed to see that this may fall in a case of convolution, since it is a possible product of Fourier Transforms. I have managed to see that

$$ \frac{6}{9 + w²} = \frac{6}{3² + w²} $$

Which indicates that for that part at least, the function

$$ \exp(-3|t|) $$

could be the inverse Fourier transform.

About the rest, I suspect that I could find the inverse of the sine, but its the imaginary exponential the one for which I can't seem to find its inverse.

Comment: Recall that for real $x$, $$e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x. $$

Comment: I have ended up with a series of cosines and sines, but I'm unsure how to follow.